# How to add multiple editable fields in page layout in SP 2013 (office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, site

How can I place multiple page content fields so I can edit them from Web Interface...? I tried copy pasting snippet from gallery but content in both fields are same (from second field)

For testing purposes, I have created two columns (in a table row) in Page Layout. Now I want to put different text in both fields. Both texts should be editable through the browser. I'd place page content field twice but as I said the content is same. Please help me I m new in SharePoint.

Editing
[image: screenshot]

After Editing
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple, use below steps.

1. Add site column "MyColumn". You can do this step through SPD2013 or portal.
2. Add this column to Pages library. Use Portal to do this.
3. Add the internal name of this column "MyColumn" to field reference of copied snippet.

For #3
There will be FieldName attribute in copied snippet (Just find FieldName="{guid value}"). You only need to change it to FieldName="MyColumn"

Comment: can you please give how tos on second and third step. I am new to SP

Comment: Refer below for #2 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/add-publishing-columns-to-content-types-lists-or-libraries-HA102898575.aspx

Comment: Hope this helped you...

Comment: +1 but I still need to check if that works

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to change the `Field Name`value under the `Misc` heading in the `Customization - Page Field` section in the snippets gallery.  Hit Update and copy the new snippet.

Comment: It gives error on the page if we change the name.