# How do I get the internal name of a custom site column?

Tags: site-column

I need to find the internal name of a site column I created. I'm trying to complete the third step in [this StackExchange answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80222/how-to-add-multiple-editable-fields-in-page-layout-in-sp-2013-office-365).

Comment: Are you creating it with sharepoint designer?

Comment: I'm creating the site column through the web, getting the page content snippet from the gallery, and adding code to my page layout in SharePoint Designer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into the list settings for the list and click on the field you created, you will see the internal field name in the URL.

If you created it as MyColumn, it would be MyColumn. If you created it as MyColumn and renamed it to My Column or something different entirely, it will be MyColumn still. If you created it like My Column, it will look like My_x200_Column or something similar.

Comment: OK thanks, it must be called MyColumn then. I was thinking it would be more random.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the below way:

1) Navigate to List Settings:
[image]

2) Click on the column
[image]

3) Check the URL parameter "Field"
[image]

This is the internal name.